# Entity Framework multiple Where statements as ORs

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Edit - using IQueryable, not an in memory collection.

So I basically want to tack on Where clauses based on some flags, but not have them act as ANDs. So let's say I want results where "Foo" is true Or "Bar" is true. I'm currently doing this...

```
results = results.Where(r => r.Foo || r.Bar);
```

which is fine, but there's a lot of conditions that I need to add ORs to and if I could chain them after each other it would make the code much more readable.

Is there any SIMPLE way to do it like the following, but using OR instead of AND.

```
if (something)
    results = results.Where(r => r.Foo)
if (somethingElse)
    results = results.Where(r => r.Bar)
```

It's not really worth it to me if I have to build Expression objects and stuff like that, or use a 3rd party library, just wondering if there was something simple I wasn't seeing.

Also, I thought about using `Union()`, but it seemed to perform slower(although it was more readable).

Some more info that could help. Basically my conditions are user roles. And they can be in any combination of roles, but each one should add an OR condition to the "results". So yeah, the enum flag thing that someone mentioned could help here.

Comment: you could try to implement it yourself - but you'd need to manipulate expression-trees - if you really have this much "or" clauses you might wonder if there is a *smell* in there

Comment: btw: from a syntax standpoint: just break the lines - it should not *look* this much worse than a new `.Where(` each line (maybe even better)

Comment: you could take a look at using `Queryable.Concat(IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>)` it runs much faster than `Union`, but means that each queryable could produce duplicates of items...`Concat` equates to `Union ALL` and `Union` equates to `Union`.

Comment: The callable you're passing to `Where` can be as large as you want, so you can use whatever syntax you like to produce the boolean that determines whether each element stays in the filtered enumerable. You're not limited to a single expression, you can have multiple statements.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how your second snippet is equivalent to the first one. It doesn't seem to find all elements where `element.Foo` or `element.Bar` is true; instead you're introducing a couple of new bools out of nowhere.

Comment: if r.[Property] is a bool and there are a lot of bools getting compared then you need to tweak the design a bit,  please consider using Enum (Attributed with Flags?) .

Comment: Asad - I know they are not the same, I was just using that as an example of using multiple `Where` statements

Comment: Aron - I wouldn't want duplicates, would calling Distinct() after negate any performance gains?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use PredicateBuilder.
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

It's a dozen lines and it lets you do this:

```
Expression<...> filter = PredicateBuilder.False();
if (something)
    filter = filter.Or(r => r.Foo);
if (somethingElse)
    filter = filter.Or(r => r.Bar);
return results.Where(filter);
```

This gives you all the same performance benefits as if you had written:

```
if (something && somethingElse)
    return results.Where(r => r.Foo || r => r.Bar)
else if (something)
    return results.Where(r => r.foo)
else if (somethingElse)
    return results.Where(r => r.Bar)
etc...
```

Comment: I have seen this, but I need to stay away from 3rd party libraries in this case. This is what I want though, so upvoting for future readers.

Comment: Only gives you the same performance in SQL not in C#, building expressions dynamically takes much longer.